# pyramid, оптимизация задачи.

Tags: c, оптимизация

Условие задачи

Вывести в консоль числовую пирамидку на total строк.
В каждой строке числа идут от единицы до номера строки через пробел.
Пропустить rows строк и cols столбцов.
В выводе не должно быть пустых строк до и после чисел.
Целые положительные числа total, rows и cols считать с клавиатуры.

Пример ввода

5 3 2

Пример вывода

3 4  
   3 4 5

Решение :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int total, rows, cols;

scanf("%d %d %d", &total, &rows, &cols);

if ( rows < cols ) {
    rows += 1;
}

for ( int i = rows + 1; i <= total; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = cols + 1; j < i; j++ ) {
        printf("%d ", j);
    }
    printf("%d\n", i);
}    
}
```

Есть ли какие то предложения как сделать красивее, или короче? )

Comment: Спасибо вы правы!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас ошибка:
вместо: `if ( rows < cols ) rows += 1;`
надо: `if ( rows < cols ) rows = cols;`

если точно читать условие - то не должно быть последнего переноса строки!
как-то так:

```
for ( int i = rows + 1; i <= total; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = cols + 1; j < i; j++ ) printf("%d ", j);
    printf("%d ", i);
    if ( i != total ) printf("\n");
}
```

а так - всё нормально написано!

Comment: Может и так, но так сказали что бы был перенос строки в конце))

Comment: Просто обратил внимание на
> ...В выводе не должно быть пустых строк...

Comment: Там имелось в виду что после последнего числа не должно быть пробела.

Answer (score 1):

[@timka_s](/users/1192/timka_s) написал все правильно относительно исправления алгоритма.

Относительно оптимизации предлагаю такой текст:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int total, rows, cols;

scanf("%d %d %d", &total, &rows, &cols);

if (rows < cols ) rows = cols;

int j;//объявляем сразу, чтобы не делать это каждый раз при начале внутреннего цикла
for ( rows++, cols++ ; rows <= total; rows++ ) {
    for ( j = cols; j <= rows; j++ ) {
        printf("%d ", j);
    }
   putchar ('\n'); //эта функция работает быстрее
}
return 0; //сразу привыкаем к грамотному стилю программирования
}
```